# Entity framework code first - association on "polymorphic" columns

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:

### 1. Invoice

InvoiceID int PRIMARY KEY

### 2. Order

OrderID int PRIMARY KEY

### 3. Transaction

TransactionID int PRIMARY KEY

Source int

Category string

On table "Transaction", Source (unfortunately) is behaving as a "polymorphic"(??) foreign key (there must be an actual term for that - sorry for my ignorance) that depending on the Category column it'll contain the ID of Invoice or Order.

However there's no actual foreign key.

Using EF 4.1 code first, anyone has any idea how I would create the proper associations?

Help is appreciated!
Thanks

### Solution

Uh... Embarrassment is kicking in... I can just map it same way regardless of any actual DB foreign key.

I was having problems while trying to do that but basically wasn't related to this. I had computation properties that I didn't ask the context to ignore which was generating wrong queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh... Embarrassment is kicking in... I can just map it same way regardless of any actual DB foreign key.

I was having problems while trying to do that but basically wasn't related to this. I had computation properties that I didn't ask the context to ignore which was generating wrong queries.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should create two nullable FKs instead of weak reference like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I'm not sure I can make any change to the actual database structure. Would it be possible to do this without touching the db?